# How to add swipe gesture to my calendar app in Android

Tags: android, swipe, swipe-gesture

I want to create an app with a calendar like this:

[calendar overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8F9o.png)

[calendar popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YAyX.png)

Swiping left or right will add or subtract a month, clicking a cell will show a popup containing a description notification. I need ideas or links or code references. Can you help me?

Comment: You can use the Material calender view library https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: It doesn't work so, what you have tried so far. What you have done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewPager for your calendar